# error with loading data from web in android

Tags: java, android

i've added a column (named load_more) to the end of a recyclerview and each time i touch this column it should download ten more columns from a url. the first time that I touch load_more, it works properly but for the second time, program crashes.
this is the code of loading data to the recyclerview:

```
public class category extends AppCompatActivity {

private String url = "http://iranradiotherapy.ir/api/get_category_posts/?include=title,date&id=";
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private adapter adapter;
private int page_counter;
private String page_number;
private boolean flag;
private int current;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String cat_id = b.getString("category_id");
    url += cat_id;
    Toast.makeText(category.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    flag = true;
    page_counter = 1;
    page_number= "&page=";

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    get_data();

}

private void get_data() {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + page_number + page_counter, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    JSONObject temp = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String post_title = temp.getString("title");
                    String post_id = temp.getString("id");
                    String post_date = temp.getString("date");

                    hashMap.put("post_title", post_title);
                    hashMap.put("post_date",  post_date);
                    hashMap.put("post_id", post_id);

                    data.add(hashMap);

                }
                final HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("load_more", "load_more");
                data.add(hashMap);

                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.category_recycler_view);

                adapter = new adapter(data);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                flag = true;

                recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerTouchListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        if (data.get(position).equals(hashMap)) {
                            load_more();
                        }
                        else {
                            Intent i = new Intent(category.this, post.class);
                            i.putExtra("post_id", data.get(position).get("post_id"));
                            category.this.startActivity(i);
                        }

                    }
                }));

            } catch (Exception e ) {
                Toast.makeText(category.this, "error 1 : " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(category.this, "error 2 : " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

private void load_more() {
    if (flag){
        flag = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "load more data " + current, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        page_counter++;
        get_data();
        data.remove(data.size() - 1 );
    }
}
```

}

and this is the adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position + 1  == data.size()) {
        holder.title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.date.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.load_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        HashMap<String, String> d = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(d.get("post_title"));
        holder.date.setText(d.get("post_date"));
        holder.load_more.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log too?

Comment: i am not using a virtual device connected to android studio, so i don't have a crash log :(